# How to add "navigation:Page" element for Xaml using JAVA with a colon init?

Tags: java, silverlight, xaml, intellij-idea, element

Hi I am generating a XAML using JAVA (IntelliJ), everything is fine until I want to insert an element with a colon init? How can I achief this?

I am able to generate `<Page>` with this code

```
Element page;
page = new Element("Page", u.getDefaultNamespace() );
```

When I want to get this element `<navigation:Page>` I did like this

```
Element page;
page = new Element("navigation:Page", u.getDefaultNamespace() );
```

but it doesn't work, it gives me a lot of errors in IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I found it

```
Element page;
page = new Element("Page", u.getNavigationNamespace() );
```

you have to have this function in your code

```
public Namespace getNavigationNamespace() { 


Namespace.getNamespace("navigation","clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation");

}
```